# How to customize Emacs's completion start for `irony-mode`, C/C++?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, completion

I use irony-mode https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode for C/C++ completion, but I find it starts completion when 3 characters entered. How can I customize this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using company-mode as backend you can customize `company-minimum-prefix-length'.